# Move some uv-islands from one UV to new UV. Is it possible?

Tags: uv

I have two UVs on one object. In the first UV-map some uv-islands are already prepared. I want to move/copy them to the second UV-map. I think it's like replacing the position of vertices of some uv-islands from the first UV-map to the second UV-map.

[image]